# absence makes the heart grow fonder

Tags: proverbs, infinitive-constructions

Why does the idiom:

> absence makes the heart grow fonder

have the form of `grow` and not `grows`?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have already makes. A structure such as  makes + grows, two finite verb forms, does not occur in English nor any other language. grow is an infinitive.

Comment: The grow goes with the heart and the makes goes with the absence, right?! Regarding `nor any other language` it is quite not accurate though.

Comment: Have a look at the verb construction to make someone do something. Josh 61 has just explained it to you. You misunderstand the construction completely. You should have a look at a grammar,  accusative + infinitive.Do you know a language that can use "makes grows"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a construction with the use of *make* as a  causative verb,  ( similar construction are with *let, have and get*)

[Make](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/let.html):

FORM

> - [make + person + verb (infinitive without to - as in the imperative construction) ]

USE

> - This construction means "to force someone to do something."

Examples:

> - My teacher made me apologize for what I had said.
>     Did somebody make you wear that ugly hat?
>     She made her children do their homework.